# Adding a text area before the Buy Now button of a WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to add an input before the Buy Now button on each single product page via WooCommerce hooks.

This is the action I've been using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation', array( $this, 'insert_text_area'), 10 );
```

This is the function:

```
public function insert_text_area() {
    error_log('insert text area called');
    echo "<input type='date' placeholder='01/01/12'>";
}
```

It does not get triggered. I've checked the single-product template file, which calls `do_action` for `woocommerce_before_single_variation`.

There are no errors in my log.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had same issue, you could copy the template too child theme and add over their. that what i did, but its not the perfect solution in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have issues with your Class construction? or are you even using a Class?

the method you posted only applies when your hook and function is inside a Class,

try this, this is the standard method, (not within the class)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'insert_text_area' );

function insert_text_area() {
    error_log('insert text area called');
    echo "<input type='date' placeholder='01/01/12'>";
}
```

if you are using a Class, you need to provide the whole code of your Class and how you call it

Comment: My code is in a Class, which is as a Wordpress function. I have other hooks called the same way, which work fine, so it's not a problem there.

Comment: if you are hooking different functions in the same action, make sure they have different priority